# Flutter Background is white when navigate from specific screens

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The screen's background is white when I navigate from one screen.
not sure why.

```
Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/main.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child:...
)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please share code for navigating to another screen and another screen code as well

Comment: To play screen
Navigator.pushNamed(context, PlayPage.pageId);
from play screen to main screen
TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                            context, MyHomePage.pageId, (route) => false);
                      },
                      child: const Icon(
                        Icons.home_outlined,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),

Comment: can you try Navigator.pop() to go back to the previous screen?

Comment: Thanks it worked, do you by any chance know why that happened?

Answer (score 0):

**if Your Using Expanded Widget, please use correctly**